# VS2008 copies to clipboard on double-click

Tags: visual-studio-2008, text-editor, clipboard

since some days ago I have a problem with VS2008 in a daily task.

Every time **I double click a word in the text editor, it goes automatically to the clipboard** (as if I pressed <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> after the double-click), which is really annoying.

I've googled but I found nothing. I've search through VS2008's options and found nothing.

I don't remember clicking on such an option (I wouldn't have done so). Maybe I did without being aware of, or maybe it was a keyboard shortcut that activated it.

How can I turn off this option?

Comment: I've rebooted my computer, and VS2008 started working normally. The strange thing is that I had this issue yesterday, I turned off the PC, and this morning it was there again. So: one reboot did not solve. Another one did solve. Very strange.

Comment: Once again the problem is back. I started working this morning, the double-click was ok. After lunch, the mysterious behavior came back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found it... It was an old dictionary software that, when running, was monitoring for doublie-clicks and the clip-board, to do automatic searches...

Comment: Thanks, @Bruno! This was driving me crazy until I saw your comment, which led me to discover that it was my Oxford English Dictionary on CDROM (v4.0) which was causing the problem. By default the app installs a global hook to copy-to-clipboard upon double click! This can be a useful feature from time to time, but certainly not as a global fixure!

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that some key on your keyboard has been accidentally stuck up.

I had this weird behavior a few times and found that the keyboard's control key was stuck down.

Probably you are having the same problem.
Can't think of any other thing.

Comment: Hmm, I would say that it is unlikely. I have no other noticeable strange behaviors. Also, it only happens (the automatic ctrl+c on double-click phenomenon) on VS2008.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: Is it possible that you have a macro enable in VS that emulates this action .
Just check under your macros, whether some have been accidentally added.

Comment: Anything like the Visual Studio 2008 PowerCommands extension installed, probably that may be working overtime.
Try disabling it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have Visual Assist X or Resharper installed that could be malfunctioning or misconfigured, try disabling them.